# Accessing my S3 bucket in Amazon

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json'); 

var params = {
        Bucket: 'test-dev-2',
        Key: file,
        Body: data
    };


    s3.putObject(params, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success");
        }
```

i alredy setup the credencials in my AwsConfig.json file, and the console it's returning this error:

```
{ [TimeoutError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: Wed Oct 08 2014 16:05:18 GMT-0300 (BRT),
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     time: Wed Oct 08 2014 16:05:18 GMT-0300 (BRT),
     originalError: 
      { message: 'Connection timed out after 1000ms',
        code: 'TimeoutError',
        time: Wed Oct 08 2014 16:05:18 GMT-0300 (BRT) } } }
```

The credentials are not wrong.. Anyone knows why the error?

Comment: getting the same issue, but intermittently.  Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your json file should look something like this (I addded a few "asdf" in there : )

`{
  "accessKeyId": "ACIAIasdfasdfBEF",
  "secretAccessKey": "1+eOuyasdfasdasdfEn1",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "apiVersions": {
    "s3": "2006-03-01",
    "ses": "2010-12-01"
  }
}`

Also, in your AWS console, make sure that user key has access to S3. Create a new user group, add the "S3 Full" permissions to that group, and create a new user that is part of that security group (**not your administrator group!**)

One more. I didn't see how you create that `s3` variable. I create mine like this server start:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath( './aws-config.json' );
AWS.s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Then in code I access it similar to you: `AWS.s3.putObject(...)`

Comment: Hei @clay, i did everything, i create a new group and a new user and assign this user for this group.. but still having the same issue...

Comment: Hey @Nescau, I'm not sure what the problem could be. Post back here when you figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after trying all options

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "accessKey";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "SecretAccessKey";
```

But not a good practice to hard code security keys. So will update this post soon with secure options as recommended by aws

Answer (score 0):

It is important to instantiate config before getting s3 object.

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsCredentials.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```